# org - keyboard shortcut to promote text to heading

Tags: org-mode, text-editing

How to promote a text line to a heading in org-mode?

ie: I start writing text and only later wants to structure it:

```
here's a start typing some text.
and continue on a 2nd line
and even a 3rd line.
but here I already start typing my 2nd paragraph
a new line of text
```

After exiting insert mode, now I would like to promote the 1st and 4th lines into heading like:

```
* here's a start typing some text.
    and continue on a 2nd line
    and even a 3rd line.
* but here I already start typing my 2nd paragraph
    a new line of text
```

thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be looking for the [org-toggle-heading](http://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-editing.html#index-org_002dtoggle_002dheading-167) function, bound by default to `C-c *`.

> Convert headings to normal text, or items or text to headings.

Answer (score 1):

If using [spacemacs](http://spacemacs.org):

- In **master** repository: `SPC SPC org-insert-heading RET` will promote a text line to an heading.
- In **develop** repository: the keyboard shortcut `, i h` will additionally do the same.

If using emacs (*without spacemacs*): `M-x org-insert-heading RET`

> edit: Depending on the spacemacs' used repository:
>
> edit2: I corrected my answer to reflect @Stefan remarks.

Comment: Please be a bit less terse.  What does `//, i h` mean?  How do you use it?

Comment: @Stefan I edited my previous answer. Let me know if you need further help with that.
Cheers

Comment: You might want to make it more clear that your answer presumes the use of Spacemacs.  In a default Emacs config, you'd do `M-x org-insert-heading RET` instead.

Answer (score 1):

A sligtly easier solution (with default keybinding) is to use "Meta-Enter" (aka <kbd>M-RET</kbd>) at the beggining of the line you want to promote to a heading.

Comment: Are you sure?  In my test here, org-mode binds `S-ret` to `org-table-copy-down` and when I use it on a plain text line it just complains "Not in table data field".

Comment: @ Stefan: My bad, I tested on my computer before answering that it was M-Enter, but somehow I got all mixed in when posting my answer I have updated it to reflect this.